# App works locally but crashes on Heroku because of Databases connection

Tags: python, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku

Stack communities,

I need your help. I’ve just written my first app in Python with the dash libraries. I am now trying to deploy thanks to the Heroku frameworks. It first works but when trying to connect it my database (PostGre), it crashed. I think it’s because my connection btw Heroku/PostGre SQL is not working correctly.

I’ve tried many changes within my code but still don’t understand why my app crash.

When I try to run the app, I get the following error within the heroku log :

[Image of the Heroku error within the server log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFj47.png)

My code can be found here in my [Github repositorie](https://github.com/Arthurmf01/IAG_Project).

As of now, my database consists of a giant CSV master file because I want to keep it simple for now.

Link to the Database (Private): https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/iag-test1/Test1.csv

*On Heroku it seems that I should use the [AWS-S3 and connect it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql). But I didn't manage to do it.

The goal of this project is to build an end-to-end visualization tool in python and deploy it. (I decided to use Dash Library and Heroku to deploy it). Maybe I should switch to AWS...

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated…

Comment: "App crashed" isn't much of an error message.  Have you looked at the webserver error log?

Comment: please tell me this --> https://github.com/Arthurmf01/IAG_Project/blob/master/app.py#L22 is not your real database credentials

Comment: @JohnGordon First Thanks for your help : the Heroku server log is in fact not super precise. Here is the complete error message it gave me. :                    
2019-03-11T18:46:31.485215+00:00 app[web.1]:     if unlink and _sock_type(sock_name) is UnixSocket:

Comment: Hi @aws_apprentice no. So basicaly I tried to follow some tuto within the Heroku website. The database link I created with S3 is the folowing: 
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/iag-test1/Test1.csv

Comment: Edit the question to include the full error message.

Comment: Done ! @JohnGordon